# Why does Lex Luthor want Batman dead?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Traditionally, Lex Luthor is an enemy of Superman, as shown in films like *Superman* and *Superman Returns*.

However, in the movie *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice*, Lex forces Superman to bring him Batman's head. Does he really want to kill Batman? If yes, then why?

Comment: Batman is a vigilante, and has no moral quandaries about breaking into or stealing from lex Corp. As we see in the end, he stole data from Lex regarding metas, a prelude to Justice League. Batman is an inconvenience to Lex. That's all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Lex doesn't actually want to kill Batman - he wants to kill Superman.**

All Lex Luthor wants to do throughout *Batman V Superman: Dawn of Justice* is kill Superman, as he fears that a man as powerful as Superman will one day become a dictator of sorts, using his godlike powers to take over the world.

By forcing Superman to fight Batman by taking Martha Kent hostage, Lex hopes that Batman will use the Kryptonite he stole from Lex to kill Superman - which very nearly happens.

It's worth noting that Lex has been baiting the two of them into battle for some time, setting up a series of events that lead Bruce Wayne/Batman to come to the same conclusion that Lex has - that Superman is too dangerous to live.

As such, Batman is nothing more than a pawn in the game that Lex Luthor is playing.

Comment: Was Lex also expecting Bruce to enters into his facility and stole that Kryptonite? Coz, it was clear that Lex had been intercepting the cheques to Keefe, and sending them back to Bruce, so that one day Bruce will take steps to kill the Superman. If Lex planned well about a fight between Bruce and Kent, then Bruce itself in a need of Kryptonite to be stronger.

Comment: @MishraShreyanshu I'm not 100% sure about that as I haven't seen the film since it was released about 6 months ago, but I think so. You also need to remember that if Batman failed to kill Superman, Lex did have Doomsday as a back-up plan.

Comment: I'd add to this that no matter who comes out on top if Batman fights Superman (assuming one of them kills the other anyway), Lex has won.  Either Superman is dead, or Lex has clear proof that the alien is as dangerous as he has been saying, which will turn public opinion against Superman.  Either way, he wins.  So long as one kills the other.  If of course that doesn't happen (as it didn't), then he has his backup plan of unleashing Doomsday, a monster which he believed he could control.

Answer (score 4):

Lex wants Batman dead because look at what Batman can do: he tears through Luthor's security on several occasions in the film and figures out what he's doing with the Kryptonite and then makes his own weapon out of it. Batman is a threat. Period. But Luthor believes Superman could kill him easily, so makes Superman do it so he can show the world what Superman "really" is. But of course Batman wins because he's Batman. As it should be.

Comment: A straight forward comment from Batman fan? But the point you mentioned that "Superman would easily kill Batman and Lex will get another chance to show what Superman" was may be a plan of Lex.

Comment: I'm kind of having trouble making sense of your English, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Did it ever occur to anybody that it's simply a game. He's mad. He's Lex Luthor....He knew Batman could do the job and he's always one step ahead, get rid of the greater inconvenience and then take care of the light work later on so he can pull the strings to control the rest of the world. He knew their identities like he knew the identities of the rest of the Justice League, it was fun to him. Identify the threats  to his Empire  seek and  Destroy all memetahumans. There's a slight indication that Lionel Luthor had already began work due to Wonder Woman that's why he had a file on them. He made a reference to his father in the movie about the painting and it should be flipped because he already knows about Darkseid. He didn't count on Batman folding or finding the krytonite, so Batman actaully became a pawn later in movle. He underestimated his compassion. The bottom line,  it's about power with Lex Luthor you guys are thinking way too hard.